# How print each object's toString in a different line using a toString in another class?

Tags: java

I have four classes Part, Battleship and Board, Game. In the part class I have a toString method which is called in the Battleship class. In the Battleship class I a toString method which is called in the toString method which is in the class Board. I need to call the toString methods for each object (battleship) in a different line

```
public class Part 
{

   public String toString()
   {

       if (destroyed == true)
       {
           return "[X]";
       }
       else
       {
           return "[]";
       }
   }
}
```

Second Class:

```
public class Battleship 
{
    private Part[] part;
    public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";

        for (Part p: part )
        {
            result += p.toString();
        }
        return result;

    }
}
```

Third class:

```
public class Board 
{
     private Battleship[] battleships = new Battleship[5];

     public String toString()
    {
        String result = "";

        for (Battleship b: battleships )
        {
            result += b.toString();
        }

        return result;

    }
}
```

The fourth class (Driver)

```
 public class Game 
 {
     public static void main(String[] args)
    {

        Board testmeBoard = new Board();

        System.out.println(testmeBoard.toString());


    }   
}
```

Please note that each battleship has a different number of parts. I know how to use if statement for this but I get something like this [][][][][][][][][][][][].Instead I want to print the toString for each battleship in a different line.

Please if something is not clear comment it and I will reply immediately.
Thanks so much for your time

Comment: where is your main code ?

Comment: How about `result += b.toString() + "\n";`? Is that what you mean?

Comment: what exactly you want to print ?

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I've added the 'Game' method which has the main method. I didn't want to print the whole code for each class as that would take the ages to read. Instead I tried to provide related informations to my question as much as I could. Thanks

Comment: @Mohsen_Fatemi I am trying to print the size of each ship as [] depending on how many parts it has (E.g. small ship has 3 parts therefore [] [] [] ) and so for each Battleship I want to print the size in a different line

Comment: @thatguy  Thanks so much !! It worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
result += b.toString() + "\n";
```

you will have a return line after the last print though.

Comment: If you just copy and paste the comment, at least format it right.

Comment: nope we did respond on the same time, or at least i didnt recieve notification in time

Comment: To be honest I first saw @thatguy comment.

Comment: lol this flame! are we really talking about a \n? honest i didnt notice